# React Native Axios Request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, react-native, axios

I am trying to delete data from the database by using AXIOS Post method.

I have created an API delete function on my back-end code and used POSTMAN to verify. With POSTMAN, I can create and delete data from database. However, on React Native, when calling the delete function, I am getting '*Request failed with status code 404*'.

*Below, I have added code snippets from React Native create/delete function and Back-End create/delete function. React native console screenshot and the app interface screenshots are provided as well.*

**React-Native create and delete function:**

```
//Add date and time
addDateTimeAppt = () => {
    let self = this;
    AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token').then((keyValue) => {
        console.log('Freelancer Create Screen (keyValue): ', keyValue);
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: Constants.API_URL + 'appointment_f/create_appointment/',
            data: {
                app_date_start: self.state.textAppointmentDate,
                start_time: self.state.textAppointmentTime,
                end_time: self.state.textEndTime,
            },
            headers: {
                'X-API-KEY': Constants.API_KEY,
                'Authorization': keyValue,
            },
        }).then(function (response) {
            self.setState({
                timeSlots: [
                    ...self.state.timeSlots,
                    {
                        apptdate: self.state.textAppointmentDate,
                        appttime: self.state.textAppointmentTime,
                        endTime: self.state.textEndTime,
                    }
                ],
            });
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
}

//delete date and time
deleteDateTimeApi = (id) => {
    let self = this;
    AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token').then((keyValue) => {
        console.log('from delete: ', Constants.API_URL + 'appointment_f/delete_appointment/')
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: Constants.API_URL + 'appointment_f/delete_appointment/',
            data: {
                app_date_start: self.state.textAppointmentDate,
                start_time: self.state.textAppointmentTime,
                end_time: self.state.textEndTime,
            },
            headers: {
                'X-API-KEY': Constants.API_KEY,
                'Authorization': keyValue,
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
        }).then(function (response) {
            const filteredData = this.state.timeSlots.filter(item => item.id !== id);
            this.setState({ timeSlots: filteredData });
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);                
            console.log(error.response);
        });
    });
}
```

**Back-End create and delete function:**

```
//Create Appointment using CodeIgniter
public function create_appointment_post(){
    $save['freelancer_id'] = $this->user->comp;
    $start = new DateTime($this->post('app_date') . ' ' . $this->post('start_time'));
    $end = new DateTime($this->post('app_date') . ' ' . $this->post('end_time'));
    $save['app_date_start'] = $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $save['app_date_end'] = $end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $this->freelancer_timeslot_model->save($save);

    $this->response($save, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}

//Delete Appointment using CodeIgniter
public function delete_appointment_post(){
    $f_id = $this->post('freelancer_id');
    $app_date_start = $this->post('app_date_start');
    $app_date_end = $this->post('app_date_end');

    $timeslot = $this->freelancer_timeslot_model->get_by(
        array(
            'freelancer_id' => $f_id, 
            'app_date_start' => $app_date_start,
            'app_date_end' => $app_date_end,
        ), TRUE);
    if(!empty($timeslot)){
        $this->freelancer_timeslot_model->delete($timeslot->id);
        $this->response(['status' => TRUE], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }else {
        $this->response([
            'status' => FALSE,
            'message' => 'No record found'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

**React Native Console.log():**

[image: console screenshot]

**App Interface:**

[image: app screenshot]

Comment: Can you also add a screenshot of it successfully working in postman

Comment: Hi, I have solved this issue. It was the problem with my RN Api. Inside my axios, the data which I was sending were incorrect.